# #ifndef in C being ignored?

Tags: c, conditional-compilation

I have a bit of code where I want to have logging only if DEBUG is defined. So I though I might be able to replace a Token (here: "DEBUGLOG") with the comment string "//". But how to do?

```
    #ifndef DEBUG
     #define DEBUGLOG //
    #endif

[...] 
    DEBUGLOG        printf("Debug String"\n);
[...]
```

There is no definition of DEBUG somwhere else in the code. But my gcc compiles this line and the program itself executes the printf();

Why?

I tried to include it in parantheses like this, but it gets an compile error:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
 #define DEBUGLOG "//"
#endif
```

This is the compiler message:

```
beispiel.c:45:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘printf’
 DEBUGLOG printf("Debug String"\n);
          ^
```

Any hints?

Comment: Can your compiler output its preprocessed code? If you do, you might find that comments are stripped out before preprocessing, and the macro expands to "nothing".

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it.
"comments are stripped out before preprocessing" - at this first stage it is not yet a comment.
Then the preprocessor follows and replaces the string with "//".
And then I have a comment in which the compiler can not deal with as step 1 is already done?

Strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up the [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases), you will find that the Phase where preprocessor is executed (Phase 4) is **after** the phase where comments are replaced by a white space character (Phase 3).

> **Phase 3**
>   1) The source file is decomposed into comments, sequences of whitespace characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), and preprocessing tokens, which are the following
>   ...
>   2) **Each comment is replaced by one space character**
>
> **Phase 4**
>   1) **Preprocessor is executed.**

**So in Phase 3 the line:**

```
#define DEBUGLOG //
```

becomes:

```
#define DEBUGLOG
```

**And in Phase 4 the line:**

```
DEBUGLOG        printf("Debug String"\n);
```

becomes:

```
printf("Debug String"\n);
```

And that is why your `printf` is executed.

And when you put it quotes (`"//"`), that line becomes:

```
"//"   printf("Debug String"\n);
```

The quotes (`""`) will not be removed. And this is a compiler error.

Comment: Ok, got it so far.
But why do I get an error when using "//"? It will become to "//" instead of // exactly, right?

Is there a way to get what I want without +ifdef lines for every call?

Comment: @Christian: Updated the answer to include this aspect as well.